# Completly draw line with Fast Triangles (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, tikz-arrows

Can I use the arrow tip `Fast Triangle` (page 212 in 3.0.0 manual) for the complete path? (or make it look like this)

## What I got so far

(needs TikZ 3.0.0)

```
\documentclass[margin=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, draw] (a) {a};
    \node[circle, draw, right=of a] (b) {b};

    \draw [f/.tip = Fast Triangle, 
        line width=1ex, 
        {Triangle Cap[reversed] }-{[bend] Triangle Cap[] . ffffff}]
        (a) to [bend left] (b);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Result

[image: result]

Comment: `\path[f/.tip = Fast Triangle, line width=1ex, tips=true, arrows={[bend] f[reversed]-fffffff}] (a) to [bend left] (b);` looks good to me. (Notice no `draw` but arrow tips via `tips = true`.) Just `arrows={[bend] -ffffffff}` almost works as well but the last one might touch `a`. With a bit of math and the `decorations` library to access the length of the path we could figure out how many `f`s we need.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to create something similar with the `decorations` library. (No need for tikz 3.0):

[image: result]

But I couldn't get it to point directly on the node.

```
\documentclass[margin=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, draw] (a) {a};
    \node[circle, draw, right=of a] (b) {b};

    \draw [decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 4pt with {
            \node[fill=black,signal from=west, signal to=east,signal, transform shape,minimum width=2pt,minimum height=5pt, inner sep=0]{};}}, decorate]
        (a) to [bend left] (b);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```